# Firebase: Incoming events slow on roaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have a firebase integration in ObjectiveC; the app deals with chat messages back and forth between two users.

Some devices were experiencing long delays in message receipts so I'm trying to get to the bottom of it with some detailed logging:

- Time on sending device the moment a message is sent (outgoing).
- Firebase Server Timestamp (on message received by firebase)
- Time on receiving device the moment a message is received.

From the data collected, I think the issue is when the user (Bob) is using an AT&T simcard while they are on roaming 3G (US sim in europe). The delays occur only for uploads and downloads to such devices. Just trying to check if anyone has ever experienced such issues before and maybe there is some workaround?

[image]

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

**How does SMS and data roaming work?**

SMS and data roaming build upon the same principles used to enable voice roaming. When you travel abroad
and you turn your handset or cellphone/laptop on, it attempts to communicate with a GSM or 3G network. Your handset may be preconfigured to actively choose a preferred network in the visited country, but you can choose your own preferred network via the handset menu.

The visited (local) network picks up the signal from your device, notes that you are a visitor and attempts to identify your home network. If there is a data roaming agreement between your home network and the visited network abroad and your network operator allows you to roam, your device will then be able to access data roaming services. In some cases, the visited network may only offer basic data services not 3G/mobile broadband services (e.g. if the visited operator has not rolled out a 3G network or if the home and visited operators have not yet signed a 3G roaming agreement).

When the user first switches their phone on, the visited network checks in real time whether the home network authenticates the customer and authorises its use abroad. But the data records (CDRs) with the details on each SMS and data session are sent to the home operator with some **delay (up to several days).**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. In this case data is all sent and received via firebase rather than SMS so I think it's just upload/download over 3G which is being throttled. Funny thing is that this behaviour does not occur on other apps such as WhatsApp and Viber so I'm curious how they get around it

Comment: I could imagine that they use a different backend.

Comment: Backend or not they would have to deal with throttled connections in some way, else then maybe firebase is the problem rather than the throttle :/

Comment: You may need to eliminate some variables. One option is to craft up a super small test app that just writes data to a node, a timestamp for example, and responds to changes within that node. Install it on multiple devices and send some messages and log the results. As it stands it could be a random poor connection, could be throttling by the provider (that's known to happen), could be the app itself, could be the firebase server or client, could be phase of the moon. Once you eliminate your app, you can start looking at the other options.